# Get cookie from after calling a POST end point

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, spring-webflux

I am calling a POST end point from my controller. The POST end point validate the user and return a cookie. I am new to the Spring web-flux so, need to get the cookie and send it back.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/valid")
public ResponseWrapper<UserResponseDTO> validate(
    @RequestBody @Valid RequestWrapper<UserRequestDTO> request,
    HttpServletResponse res) {

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URI)
    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .build();

Mono<ResponseWrapper> response = webClient.post()
    .uri(PWD_AUTH_URI)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .syncBody(request)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ResponseWrapper.class);

ResponseWrapper<UserResponseDTO> wr = response.block();
    // how to get cookie from the webClient 
    // set into the "res" that cookie 

return wr;
}
```

Comment: use `exchange` method instead `retrieve` to consume web service response, so you can get access to `clientResponse` object from which you can access `cookies`. It is never advisable to block the reactive call.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the response's cookies via consuming the response:

```
final String cookieName = "cookie_name";
    
// Retrieves cookie from WebClient
ResponseCookie cookie = webClient.post()
        .uri(PWD_AUTH_URI)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .syncBody(request)
        .exchange()
        .map(response -> response.cookies().getFirst(cookieName))
        .block();

// Set ResponseCookie as new cookie for response
res.addCookie(new Cookie(cookieName, cookie.getValue()));
```

As [akreddy.21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7005973/akreddy-21) suggested in his comment.

Update: For more recent versions of WebClient, use:

```
        .exchangeToMono { response ->
            Mono.just(response.cookies().getFirst(cookieName))
        }
```

instead of the calls to `exchange().map()` above.